# Iterate over list of list of integer and calculate difference(java)

Tags: java

I have got a list of list as follows:

```
nestedList=[[1, 1], [4, 5], [8, 9], [11, 11]]
```

I'm trying to calculate the difference between the last element of the initial list[1, 1] and the first element of second element[4, 5]i.e 4-1=3 and so on(8-5=3,11-9=2).

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I'm trying to iterate through the lists.Calculate the difference between ending value of first list and starting value of next list.

Comment: I tried to iterate using 2 for loops and finding the difference but somehow messed up the code.

Comment: Don't post [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367051/how-to-calculate-difference-of-elements-in-list-of-list-java).

Comment: @shmosel I was not able to find any similar post.If you have a link then please share else try to answer the question.

Comment: How about `IntStream.range(1, list.length).map(i -> list[i][0]-list[i-1][1]).toArray()`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Upon request, implemented support for List of List that contains Integers**

```java
    int sumOfDifference(List<List<Integer>> nestedList) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int index = 1; index < nestedList.size(); index++) {
            List<Integer> values = nestedList.get(index);

            List<Integer> previous = nestedList.get(index - 1);

            int difference = values.get(0) - previous.get(1);

            sum += difference;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

**Example**

```java
        int sum = stack.sumOfDifference(Arrays.asList(
                Arrays.asList(1, 1),
                Arrays.asList(4, 5),
                Arrays.asList(8, 9),
                Arrays.asList(11, 11)));
```

Comment: I need it for a list of list.

Comment: Thank you @Jason. There is a small change since my result is 3,3,2 so it should be sum = difference.I was messing with the syntax in my piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Write a normal `for` loop over the list, but start at 1 instead of 0, so you can lookup the previous element using `i - 1`.

Then get previous element and its second value, and get current element and its first value, then subtract the two.

It's really quite that simple.

Comment: I'm using the same logic but still not getting the results.

Comment: @Vro If you showed your code in the question, we could help you figure out what you're doing wrong.